# RabbitMQ windows installer CLI options

Tags: rabbitmq

I have been trying to find documentation on rabbitmq windows installer possible options. So far I have found /S for silent install and /D=C:\test to specify destination. Does anyone know what is the switch for other installation options i.e. to install and start the service ?
I can't find the /S and /D in rabbitmq documentation.

Comment: I did try usual suspects of /? /h --help and they don't return anything.